# COUNTIF to show Blank if Zero

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010, circular-reference

I am using the below formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('New In'!F:F,YTD!$A2,'New In'!B:B,YTD!$P$217)=0,"",COUNTIFS('New In'!F:F,YTD!$A2,'New In'!B:B,YTD!$P$217))
```

what it needs to do is show a **blank** if the result is **zero** - It does work, to an extent - If the result is zero, it shows a blank. However, if the cell value is greater than zero, it shows a circular reference error.

Any ideas whats happened?

Comment: Circular reference... The first thing to check is if the formula you are showing is deployed within a cell covered by the ranges of the formula itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be way off here but is the formula in column 'P'?

If this is the case you may be dragging the formula down and overwriting the data in $P$217.

This would cause the circular reference in cell P217.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is fine, so you must have it within the cell range you are specifying to do the counting

`=IF(COUNTIFS(F5685:F5687,F6069,E5685:E5687,E6069)=0,"",COUNTIFS(F5685:F5687,F6069,E5685:E5687,E6069))`

^ works as expected

`=IF(COUNTIFS('New In'!F:F,YTD!$A2,'New In'!B:B,YTD!$P$217)=0,"",COUNTIFS('New In'!F:F,YTD!$A2,'New In'!B:B,YTD!$P$217))`

^ your formula for comparison